# What does the exclamation mark before class path do in ProGuard?

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard

I studying the Proguard now but im confused with the exclamation mark ! before the classpath in the settings, such as:

**-keep class !android.support.v7.view.menu.**{*;}**

what does this "!" do? does it mean that proguard will not keep this class? but if thats so why do we need it since proguard will obfuscate all the classes?

Comment: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the same thing that ! means in many other programming languages.  It negates the selection that follows.  So in your example, the keep directive will apply to everything that is *not* in the following package/class selection.

Comment: thanks Doug, so does it mean that if dont have any keep in my config file proguard will be obfuscating all the classes?

Comment: ProGuard will try to obfuscate as much as it possibly can, yes.  You should at least have the default Android rules in your project, however, or it probably won't work after obfuscation.

Comment: thanks dude, one last question for you, i have this line of rules 1.-keep class !android.support.v7.view.menu.**{*;} and it will obfuscate the MenuBuilder class in this package, but after I add this line of rule #-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }, the MenuBuilder class is not obfuscated, however, i dont see a conflict here. would you mind explain a little bit more ？ thank you so much

Comment: I don't see why the line matters at all.  Just remove it and see for yourself if things that use MenuBuilder still work the way you expect.