# Android proguard rules

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

Just wondering what exactly this means.

```
-keep class !com.my.package.** { *; }
```

Does it mean not obfuscate anything.  Does it defeat the purpose of using proguard?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the exclamation mark before class path do in ProGuard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36169430/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-before-class-path-do-in-proguard)

Answer (score 0):

It will obfuscate your package classes including sub-packages and classes in them.
Why not if the app doesn't use any external library :)